# android logcat logs chatty module line identical message

Tags: android, logcat

I am getting lots of this kind of logcat messages related to my application.

> 2019-03-13 10:05:51.065 27319-27319/com.example.fir_s1 I/chatty:
>   uid=10204(com.example.fir_s1) identical 1 line

What are these log messages? Am I missing my actual application logcat logs here?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, chatty is censoring your application's logging. You app is logging the same line more than once (almost) simultaneously. See [this similar question (and answers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587273/android-logcat-logs-chatty-module-line-expire-message) for more information.

Comment: in my case, I use `for` loop to send data to my python server. These same log messages. what should I do? Ignore these messages? or just a delay between every request?

Comment: @RohitNishad Do you need the log messages? In the SO thread I linked to there are instructions on how to disable this behavior. Otherwise you can just ignore it. It doesn't affect your application, it's only the logging that gets censored.

Answer (score 2):

Your log has been running multiple times in a short amount of time, so that the output message is collapsed.

Comment: in my case, I use `for` loop to send data to my python server. These same log messages. what should I do? Ignore these messages? or just a delay between every request?

Comment: @RohitNishad Just ignore it.