# My log messages is printing only 2 times in Android

Tags: java, android, debugging

Why in this loop "hello world" is shown just 2 times, not 20 times?

```
 for(int j=0; j<20; j++){
   Log.d("myTag","hello world");
 }
```

Please explain what's going on.

Comment: You are logging same tag and value each time , Just try `Log.d("myTag"+j,"hello world"+jj)`.

Comment: Challenging question...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is because of identical tag names or messages. Seems that it doesn't allow more than two same logs. You can use

```
for(int j=0;j<20;j++){
    Log.d("myTag" + j,"hello world");
 }
```

or

```
for(int j=0;j<20;j++){
    Log.d("myTag","hello world" + j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In logcat you can see these lines, [image]

Also you have the same issue with this loop:

```
for (j in 0..19) {
            Log.d("myTag", "${j/20}")
        }
```

But this loop runs as desired:

```
for (j in 0..19) {
            Log.d("myTag", "$j")
        }
```

Apparently Android Studio doesn't show identical logs. Also see these two links:
[android logcat logs chatty module line identical message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135203/android-logcat-logs-chatty-module-line-identical-message?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [android logcat logs chatty module line expire message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587273/android-logcat-logs-chatty-module-line-expire-message)