# Missing logs on Android logcat

Tags: java, android, logging, logcat

I noticed that logcat starts missing logs when printing at a fast pace. I reproduced the error printing different logs very quickly for the same tag, but couldn't find the reason why. The testing loop is this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
        Log.i("TestLogging", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA " + i);
        Log.i("TestLogging", "BBBBBBBBBBBBBB " + i);
        Log.i("TestLogging", "CCCCCCCCCCCCCC " + i);
        Log.i("TestLogging", "DDDDDDDDDDDDDD " + i);
        Log.i("TestLogging", "EEEEEEEEEEEEEE " + i);
        Log.i("TestLogging", "FFFFFFFFFFFFFF " + i);
        Log.i("TestLogging", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGG " + i);
        Log.i("TestLogging", "HHHHHHHHHHHHHH " + i);
    }
```

The ouput after some interations is this:

```
2020-03-06 17:19:46.974 22045-22045/? I/TestLogging: CCCCCCCCCCCCCC 428
2020-03-06 17:19:46.975 22045-22045/? I/TestLogging: FFFFFFFFFFFFFF 432
2020-03-06 17:19:46.975 22045-22045/? I/TestLogging: EEEEEEEEEEEEEE 433
2020-03-06 17:19:46.975 22045-22045/? I/TestLogging: DDDDDDDDDDDDDD 438
2020-03-06 17:19:46.975 22045-22045/? I/TestLogging: FFFFFFFFFFFFFF 442
2020-03-06 17:19:46.975 22045-22045/? I/TestLogging: CCCCCCCCCCCCCC 443
2020-03-06 17:19:46.975 22045-22045/? I/TestLogging: GGGGGGGGGGGGGG 444
2020-03-06 17:19:46.975 22045-22045/? I/TestLogging: AAAAAAAAAAAAAA 446
2020-03-06 17:19:46.975 22045-22045/? I/TestLogging: HHHHHHHHHHHHHH 446
2020-03-06 17:19:46.976 22045-22045/? I/TestLogging: BBBBBBBBBBBBBB 452
2020-03-06 17:19:46.977 22045-22045/? I/TestLogging: BBBBBBBBBBBBBB 467
2020-03-06 17:19:46.977 22045-22045/? I/TestLogging: EEEEEEEEEEEEEE 467
2020-03-06 17:19:46.977 22045-22045/? I/TestLogging: DDDDDDDDDDDDDD 470
2020-03-06 17:19:46.977 22045-22045/? I/TestLogging: HHHHHHHHHHHHHH 475
2020-03-06 17:19:46.977 22045-22045/? I/TestLogging: AAAAAAAAAAAAAA 480
2020-03-06 17:19:46.977 22045-22045/? I/TestLogging: BBBBBBBBBBBBBB 480
```

Anyone knows if there is a solution to this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be assuming that log output will always be sequential, but if/when multiple threads are writing to the logs, log entries may appear out of order. Are you sure there's a problem here?

Comment: @GabrielBauman that's a for loop, not multiple threads...logs within a thread are ordered, they'd be quite useless if they were not. The OP is quite likely hitting log throttling.  There's a limit to how quickly you can log.

Comment: @GabrielBauman Thank you! I think this is not an issue with threads as logs are clearly missing from the output, not misplaced.

Comment: @RyanMentley I thought about that, but couldn't find anything on doc or any other info about this. Can you point me to where this limit is mentioned?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587273/android-logcat-logs-chatty-module-line-expire-message is probably relevant  - you're very likely getting these `Chatty` logs

Comment: @RyanMentley My app is indeed marked as chatty. I tried to whitelist my app with PID, UID and PID/UID but none worked, it continues to collapse my logs